# Update multiple columns based off another table in DB2 V5R4M0

Tags: sql, sql-update, common-table-expression, db2-400, sql-merge

I am working on an update statement for an AS400 DB/2 table. It needs to have multiple rows updated using data from another table with matching fields. Our version of the driver displays is: 05.04.0000 OS/400 V5R4M0

I am having trouble figuring out the correct syntax to use.

Here is the basic CTE I am using to collect the correct data to use:

```
with tablesql as
              (
                select *
                from TBL1CPY
              ),
     tableAS400 as 
              (
                select *
                from TBL1 
                where LDT = '20220104' AND US ='ADMIN'
               ),
     tableSQLFrmJoin as
              (
                select s.* 
                from tablesql s, tableAS400 a
                where s.prj = a.prj AND s.PN = a.PN AND s.IN = a.IN
              )
```

Here are a few different things I have tried with the CTE:

```
1)  update TBL1 t1
    set (STS) = ( select STS from  tableSQLFrmJoin ) t2
    where t1.prj = t2.prj AND t1.PN = t2.PN AND t1.IN = t2.IN 

*this throws the error: Error Source: IBMDA400 Command, Error Message: SQL0199: Keyword Update  not expected...* 

2) MERGE INTO TBL1 t1
   USING 
   (select * from tableSQLFrmJoin) t2
   on (t1.prj = t2.prj AND t1.PN = t2.PN AND t1.IN = t2.IN) 
   when matched then
   update SET STS = 'TST'

   *this throws the error: Error Source: IBMDA400 Command, Error Message: SQL0104: Token MERGE  not expected...* 

3) update tbl1 t1, tableSQLFrmJoin t2
   set t1.STS = 'tst'
   where t1.prj = t2.prj AND t1.PN = t2.PN AND t1.IN = t2.IN 

   *this throws the error: Error Source: IBMDA400 Command, Error Message: SQL0199: Keyword Update  not expected...*
```

The result should update matching rows in tbl1 with data from the CTE "tableSQLFrmJoin"
Right now to get the query working I am just using test data for the set cases.

Using a simple,
`Select * from tableSQLFrmJoin`  works as expected. So the CTE as it's written is supported and works correctly when using a select statement.

Comment: V5R4 is something very old, see [this page](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/release-life-cycle), documentation is no more available online, and many features/optimisations have been available since. If I remember well MERGE statement was not available, and you can't use CTE with update (still today), are you stuck with V5R4 ?

Comment: @nfgl Thank you, yea unfortunately we are stuck with V5R4 until we can get everything moved over to SQL Server. I was starting to think maybe it was the CTE as well. I'm currently working on writing it without the CTE. I'll avoid the MERGE statement for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you'll need something like so

```
update TBL1 t1
set STS = (select sts
           from TBL1CPY cp
           where cp.prj = t1.prj AND cp.PN = t1.PN AND cp.IN = t1.IN
           )
where LDT = '20220104' AND US ='ADMIN';
```

Note that the above assumes there will always be a single matching row or that STS can be null if there's no matching row.

If there's no matching row and STS can't be null, then you'll need

```
update TBL1 t1
set STS = (select sts
           from TBL1CPY cp
           where cp.prj = t1.prj AND cp.PN = t1.PN AND cp.IN = t1.IN
           )
where LDT = '20220104' AND US ='ADMIN'
  and exists (select 1
              from TBL1CPY cp
              where cp.prj = t1.prj AND cp.PN = t1.PN AND cp.IN = t1.IN
             );
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked great! Sorry I forgot to mention in the original question, but how would I go about if I need more than one column updated? I was stuck just getting the basics of one column updated working, i forgot that more than one will need to be corrected during the update. I tried, set STS, Col1 = (select sts, col1 from ...  to no avail.

Comment: I think v5r4 supports row-value expressions,  `set (sts, col1) = (select sts, col1 from .... )`

Comment: Ah, missed the parenthesis. Thank you for your help! This solution worked for me.